# react-native without expo or using libraries in expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to use many useful libraries in react native. How can I use react-native without expo? or How can I use libraries in expo?

Answer (score 0):

It depends which libraries you want to use. For creating an Expo project, you can use "expo init". You can use yarn or npm. To install the libraries, do yarn add  or npm i  and just import that library in your file. You can refer this link to know the difference.
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/expo-vs-react-native-cli-a-guide-to-bootstrapping-new-react-native-apps-6f0fcafee58f
If you can elaborate on libraries, I can help you with that.

Comment: Thank you. I want to use react-native-android-pip
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-pip